# If $x_{n}\to x$ and $y_{n}\to y$, where $x\neq y$, there are $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r > 0$ such that $d(x_{n},y_{n}) > r$ for every $n > n_{0}$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces

**Exercise**

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. If $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are convergent sequences with different limits, then there are $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r > 0$ such that $d(x_{n},y_{n}) > r$ for every $n > n_{0}$.

**My attempt**

I know that $z_{n}\to z$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ iff
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d(z_{n},z) < \varepsilon).
\end{align*}

But I cannot proceed from here

This is not homework. I am really interested in understanding the theory properly.

Comment: Do you understand intuitively why this result is correct? If so you should be able to take that intuition and try to start writing a proof.

Comment: As far as I have understood, the terms of $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ must be at a distance at least as large as $r$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: That's just restating the question. What is $r$?

Comment: I think it may be related to $d(x,y)$.

Comment: It's not even clear if you know the definition of the convergence. Please state what you know and what you have tried in the post.

Comment: You're right, it is. Can you be more specific? I would advise drawing a little schematic sketch with two sequences (say in $\mathbb{R}^2$) approaching two different limits.

Comment: **HINT:** Consider the sequence $x_n-y_n$. Is it divergent? Is it convergent? If so, what is its limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=d(x,y), r=t/2>0$.  Then there exist integers $n_1,n_2>0$ such that for every $n>n_1$, $d(x_n, x)<t/4$ and for every $n>n_2$, $d(y_n, y)<t/4$. Let $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. Then by the triangle inequality for every $n>n_0$, $d(x_n,y_n)\ge t-t/4-t/4=t/2=r$.

Answer (score 1):

By contrapositive, consider $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ sequences such that $x_n\to x,y_n\to y$, where $x\neq y$, and given $\epsilon>0$ exists $n_1\in\Bbb N$ such $n>n_1\implies d(x_n,y_n)<\epsilon/3$. Since $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, given $\epsilon>0$ exists $n_2,n_3\in\Bbb N$ such $$n>n_1\implies d(x_n,y_n)<\dfrac\epsilon3,n>n_2\implies d(x_n,x)<\dfrac\epsilon3\text{ and } n>n_3\implies d(y_n,y)<\dfrac\epsilon3$$
Then set $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2,n_3\}$ and by triangular inequality $n>n_0$ implies
$$d(x,y)\leq d(x_n,x)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y)<\dfrac\epsilon3+\dfrac\epsilon3+\dfrac\epsilon3\implies d(x,y)<\epsilon$$
So $d(x,y)=0$, which is absurd since $x\neq y$. Thus must exist $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)>r$ for every $n>n_0$.

Comment: +1.  We can be a little simpler & without a contra by letting $r=d(x,y)/3.$ For all but finitely many $n$ we have $d(x,x_n)<r$ and $d(y_n,y)<r$ so $3r=d(x,y)\le d(x,x_n)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y)<r+d(x_n,y_n)+r,$ implying $r<d(x_n,y_n)$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Indeed ! Neat solution =)